# java- use scanner to read in and process one piece of information at a time

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, while-loop, system.in

I am trying to use scanner to read in several lines of input at a time. I reckon that there is something wrong with either the way I use the loop, or the way I read in information. Nothing was stored in the output array. I commented my question in the code. Can someone please help? Thank you!

```
        Scanner c = new Scanner (System.in);
        while (c.hasNextLine()){
            ArrayList <Integer> record= new ArrayList <Integer> (); // next time the while loop runs, I expect the list record to be initialized again 

            String numbers = c.nextLine();

            int n = Integer.parseInt(numbers);
            for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
                String info = c.nextLine();//then read the following n lines use for loop

                int length = info.length(); //get the length of each line
                record.add(length);
            }       

            putRecordinArray(record);//some other function to process each record(a block of several lines processed each time by the while loop)
          }
    //here I tried to print out the array A generated by other function, but nothing was stored. 
    }
```

Comment: So the problem is in the `putRecordInArray()` method?

Answer (score 0):

Your Arraylist name is `records` but you are calling it with `record` which is `records without the 's'`. You `have to add the 's'`. 
example of one of your calling statements.

```
record.add(length);
```

change to:

```
records.add(length);
```

also:

```
putRecordinArray(record);
```

change to:

```
putRecordinArray(records);
```

Hope this helps.